# Get excel file with Office JS on iPad

Tags: excel, ipad, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am currently building an office add-in that should work for word, powerpoint and excel that takes the word/powerpoint document or excel sheet as a binary file using Office JS and transfers it to a third party site with the add-in.

With word and powerpoint this works perfectly everywhere. Unfortunately there is a slight problem with excel on iPads.

The function I'm using to get the file via Office JS is `Office.context.document.getFileAsync(...)`. If you look at the API reference below, this function is supported everywhere except for excel on the iPad. I have no clue as to why this is and I was not able to find any alternative to using this function to get the excel file.

[image]

see also: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=excel-js-1.17#office-office-document-getfileasync-member(1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=excel-js-1.17#office-office-document-getfileasync-member(1))

Is there any other way to get to the file, than to use this function?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Simon